# Has anyone seen a plug like this before? It is supposed to be for a portable cooler. Wondering what it plugs into?

Tags: electrical

Has anyone seen a plug like this one before? I am wondering what it plugs into. It is on the power cord for a portable cooler, and may be for a car, RV or boat. I am wondering if it is for another country other than the U.S.

Comment: The plug has 2 horizontal prongs, about the same size as the vertical prongs on a U.S. 2-prong plug. Looks like my picture did not get added to my question.

Comment: See https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer for help adding a photo to your post.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a [NEMA 6-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_6) appliance plug. It's different so you don't plug an appliance expecting 220v into an outlet delivering 120v, which would multiply the current to dangerous levels.

Apparently they're also used in 12v (RV) applications sometimes.

See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/89242/35141.